# Find lock-unlock mismatch in code

Tags: locking, code-analysis

Does someone know if there is some software around which can quickly find any non-symmetrical call to functions that must always be called together, such as lock() / unlock(), or even C++ new / delete ?

Sure I could write my own piece of code to do so, but if I can avoid the pain...

Thank you !